# Probem installing bnlearn

Tags: py-bnlearn

i use the "pip install bnlearn", however it output as an error

```
Collecting bnlearnNote: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [15 lines of output]
      The 'sklearn' PyPI package is deprecated, use 'scikit-learn'
      rather than 'sklearn' for pip commands.
      
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
...
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the problem.
I use a higher version of python, and I install a past version of BNlearn(0.8.2). I now have escaped from the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).